# С клавиатуры вводите название товара и его кол-во, посчитать цену выбранных товаров и сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке

Tags: python, python-3.10

Здраствуйте, я псевдо программист (новичок) и с горем пополам написал предыдущее и вроде работает как по условию. Помогите пожалуйста.
Не могу написать данные пункты, просто я на этом закончился...

Приступить к покупке: С клавиатуры вводите название продукта и его   кол-во, n – выход из программы. Посчитать цену выбранных товаров и   сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке
6. До свидания.

```
# Рамки написания кода по пройденным темам: базовых структуры данных, строк, переменных, условные операторы,
# циклы, списки, кортежи, словари, множества, файлы. Код написанный не по пройденным темам, является не засчитанным.
# Клиент приходит в кондитерскую.
# Он хочет приобрести один или несколько видов продукции, а также узнать её состав.
# Реализуйте кондитерскую.
# У вас есть словарь, где ключ – название продукции (торт, пирожное, маффин и т.д.).
# Значение – список, который содержит состав, цену (за 100гр) и кол-во (в граммах).
# Предложите выбор:
# 1. Если человек хочет посмотреть описание: название – описание
# 2. Если человек хочет посмотреть цену: название – цена.
# 3. Если человек хочет посмотреть количество: название – количество.
# 4. Всю информацию.
# 5. Приступить к покупке:
# С клавиатуры вводите название продукта и его кол-во, n – выход из программы.
# Посчитать цену выбранных товаров и сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке
# 6. До свидания.

product = {'торт': [['сгущенное молоко', 'пшеничная мука', 'куриные яйца', 'сода пищевая', 'уксус',
                     'пшеничная мука', 'сахар', 'молоко', 'сливочное масло'], 10, 300],
           'пирожное': [['печенье', 'сгущенное молоко', 'сливочное масло', 'какао-порошок'], 5, 1500],
           'маффин': [['яйцо куриное', 'молоко', 'мука пшеничная', 'сахар', 'масло растительное', 'разрыхлитель',
                       'какао', 'соль'], 6, 700]
           }
while True:
    choice = input('1 - название – описание, 2 - название – цена, 3 - название – количество, 4 - Вся информация, '
                   '5 - Приступить к покупке: ')
    if choice == '1':
        for key, value in product.items():
            print(key, '-', ', '.join(value[0]))
    if choice == '2':
        for key, value in product.items():
            print(key, f'- цена: {value[1]} руб за 100гр.')
    if choice == '3':
        for key, value in product.items():
            print(key, f'- кол-во: {value[2]} гр.')
    if choice == '4':
        for key, value in product.items():
            print(f'\n {key}', '\nСостав:', ", ".join(value[0]), f'\nЦена: {value[1]} руб за 100 гр.',
                  f'\nКоличество: {value[2]} гр.')
```

Comment: что именно не получается? Ввести название продукта с клавиатуры? Ввести число n?

Comment: Приступить к покупке: С клавиатуры вводите название продукта и его кол-во, n – выход из программы. Посчитать цену выбранных товаров и сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке 6. До свидания.

Comment: Это -  часть задания, уже написаная в вопросе. И это совсем не ответ на мой вопрос. Пойми - чем полнее и понятнее ты будешь отвечать на уточняющие вопросы, тем выше вероятность, что получишь какую-то помощь. Писать ВЕСЬ код тебе тут никто не будет. Еще раз: что именно из перечисленного не получается?

Comment: Я не понимаю, я максимально изложил все что у меня есть на руках, в шапке темы написал, описал ситуацию и скинул код, что у меня вышло. Прошу помощи в остальной части кода, просто подскажите в каком направлении, я сам не уверен что код который я написал, подходит.

Comment: Не получается: С клавиатуры вводите название продукта и его кол-во, Посчитать цену выбранных товаров и сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке. (n – выход из программы. можно реализовать и через if переменная == 'n': break)

Comment: Т.е. вести с клавиатуры пункт меню получается, а название продукта не получается? 

Comment: С клавиатуры вводите название ПРОДУКТА и его КОЛ-ВО, по условию это нужно ввести одним input или выход из программы, затем программа должна, посчитать цену выбранных товаров и сколько товаров осталось в изначальном списке, с выводом результата.

Comment: вы упорно продолжаете переписывать в комментариях задачу, вместо того, чтобы ответить на мой простой вопрос.

Comment: Проблема была в корявом написании остальной части, ошибки исправил и выложил остальную рабочую уже часть кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
    else:
    cost = 0
    while True:
        name_product = input("Введите названия продукта: (торт, пирожное, маффин)\n "
                             " или введите n – выход из программы: ")
        if name_product == 'n' or name_product not in product:
            break
        gram = float(input('Сколько грамм вы хотите купить? '))
        if gram > product[name_product][2]:
            print('У нас столько нет, выберите другое кол-во или товар')
            continue
        print(cost)
        cost = cost + (gram / 100 * product[name_product][1])
        product[name_product][2] -= gram
    print(f'Вам надо заплатить {cost} руб ')
for key, value in product.items():
    print('Остатки: ', key, value[2], 'гр')
print('До свидания.')
```

Код дописан и работает в соответствии всех условий задачи!